# R create data.tables dynamically

Tags: r

Edit V2: Fixed examples, added expected output

I’m trying to dynamically create a bunch of data tables (subsets) based on two tables. The first table, the main dataset, contains all the data:

```
require(data.table)
Doc_ID <- c(3631154, 3631545, 318801)
document_type <- c('Customer Letter', 'Customer Letter', 'Refund Application')
Pages <- c(2,12,53)
dataset <- data.table (Doc_ID, document_type, Pages)
```

The second table contains all two parameters needed to create dynamic tables --  non-overlapping subsets of the main dataset.

```
document_type <- c('Customer Letter', 'Refund Application')
MoreThan3SD <- c(2, 22)
DocTableName <-c ('dt_Cust_Ltr', 'dt_Refund_App')
sdset <- data.table(document_type, MoreThan3SD, DocTableName)
```

I’m trying to get, conceptually, something like this line of code:

```
[sdset$DocTableName] <- dataset[document_type == sdset$document_type][Pages > sdset$MoreThan3SD][Pages > 0]
```

into a result like this:

```
dt_Cust_Ltr <- dataset[document_type =='Customer Letter' & Pages > 2]
dt_Refund_App <- dataset[document_type =='Refund Application' & Pages > 22]
```

That is, is there a way to use an apply function to loop through every row in sdset, to dynamically create new tables based on the information in each row of sdset -- like iterating each row of sdset into a SQL SELECT INTO query?

Comment: You might want to give a more concrete example. If these subsets are nonoverlapping, maybe just make a subset ID column in the big table or use `split` (available in the current devel version of data.table.. not really clear if you're using that package, but you tagged it...) if this is a partition.

Comment: Writing a very small illustrative example with working code - say 10 lines of data in table one and say 2 rows of table two and a clear desired output would make this a much better question.

Comment: can you give the output your expect? the conceptually example does not even run

Comment: btw `dt_Cust_Ltr <- dataset[document_type =='Customer Letter'][Pages > 2][Pages > 0]` is a redundant and inefficient way to do `dt_Cust_Ltr <- dataset[document_type =='Customer Letter' & Pages > 2]`

Comment: @JohnSmith, thanks for the &

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
Doc_ID <- c(3631154, 3631545, 318801)
document_type <- c('Customer Letter', 'Customer Letter', 'Refund Application')
Pages <- c(2,12,53)
dataset <- data.table (Doc_ID, document_type, Pages)

document_type <- c('Customer Letter', 'Refund Application')
MoreThan3SD <- c(2, 22)
DocTableName <-c ('dt_Cust_Ltr', 'dt_Refund_App')
sdset <- data.table(document_type, MoreThan3SD, DocTableName)

foo <- merge(dataset, sdset, by = "document_type")[Pages > MoreThan3SD]
for (doc_table_name in unique(foo$DocTableName)) {
  assign(doc_table_name, value = foo[DocTableName == doc_table_name, .(Doc_ID, document_type, Pages)])
}

print(grep("dt", ls(), value = T))
print(dt_Cust_Ltr)
print(dt_Refund_App)

# > print(grep("dt", ls(), value = T))
# [1] "dt_Cust_Ltr"   "dt_Refund_App"
# > print(dt_Cust_Ltr)
#     Doc_ID   document_type Pages
# 1: 3631545 Customer Letter    12
# > print(dt_Refund_App)
#    Doc_ID      document_type Pages
# 1: 318801 Refund Application    53
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a table for each row in sdset, with the tablename as sdset$DocTableName, for all records in dataset matching sdset$document_type, with Pages > sdset$MoreThan3SD, with a minimum Pages > 0 in case MoreThan3SD = 0.

Comment: can you provide the data.table inputs and output(s) data tables you require... sorry but mind is getting tired to interpret your sentence :)

Comment: The inputs are provided in the first two code blocks -- which create dataset and sdset, respectively. The desired output is provided in the 4th code block, which creates dt_Cust_Ltr and dt_Refund_App